# Always favor labels over flet?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Lisp, we have two functions to define local functions, `flet` and `labels`. Both basically do the very same, they both have the same syntax, their only (?) difference is that with `labels` the local functions can refer to each other, with `flet` they can't.

Is there any good reason to use `flet` at all? In other words: Why not always use `labels` and get rid of `flet` completely?

As far as I can see, `flet` is just a 95% subset of `labels`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `let*` is to `let` as `labels` is to `flet`

Comment: @Baggers Not quite. LABELS can refer to previous AND subsequent function bindings. LET* can refer only to previous bindings.

Comment: @Xach: Thanks man, I had that totally wrong :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither `flet` not `labels` are functions. They are special, built-in, operators.

`FLET` is the simpler construct. The defined local functions are only visible in the body. `LABELS` allows us to define recursive local functions and also mutually recursive local functions.

```
CL-USER 7 > (let ((i 5))
              (labels ((foo ()
                         (decf i) (bar))
                       (bar ()
                         (unless (zerop i)
                           (print i)
                           (foo))))
                (foo)))

4 
3 
2 
1 
NIL
```

**Thus it is good style to use the simpler `FLET` by default.**

The use of `LABELS` then indicates that the local functions are using recursion. Then by reading `LABELS` or `FLET` one can see if the local function(s) are using recursion or not.

> their only (?) difference is that with labels the local functions can refer to each other, with flet they can't.

The function defined in `flet` can't also call itself directly. Thus one can redefine an outer (possibly global) function and use the outer function in the definition.

Generally it's a good idea to not use that in user code, since it makes code harder to understand. It may be useful in generated code ... sometimes.

Comment: Wow, as always, amazing answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: it's worth noting that the example using SQRT introduces undefined behavior per http://l1sp.org/cl/11.1.2.1.2

Comment: @Xach: thanks, I was forgetting about that while trying to come up with an example...